# chrome browser shows 200(from disk cache) only if etag and last-modified-date both are used

Tags: caching, etag, request-headers, last-modified, response-headers

why does chrome browser show 200(from disk cache) only if etag and last-modified-date both are used and not if only etag response header is set ?
Note : etag generation is done correctly .
In my case I needed etag and last-modified date was not really needed

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR

- Because most of the browsers will assign a heuristic expiration time when there is no **Cache-Control** nor **explicit expiration times** based on the `Last-Modified time` [1].
- Could add `Cache-Control: must-revalidate` header into the response for cache control [2].

---

[1] https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-4.2.2

> If the response has a Last-Modified header field (Section 2.2 of
> [RFC7232]), caches are encouraged to use a heuristic expiration value
> that is no more than some fraction of the interval since that time.
> A typical setting of this fraction might be 10%.

[2] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#revalidation_and_reloading

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

New MDN link：
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#up-to-date_contents_always

> For content that’s generated dynamically, or that’s static but updated often, you want a user to always receive the most up-to-date version.
>
> If you don't add a Cache-Control header because the response is not intended to be cached, that could cause an unexpected result. Cache storage is allowed to cache it heuristically — so if you have any requirements on caching, you should always indicate them explicitly, in the Cache-Control header.
>
> Adding no-cache to the response causes revalidation to the server, so you can serve a fresh response every time — or if the client already has a new one, just respond 304 Not Modified.